# how do I access facebook developer app?

Tags: facebook

when I click the link to the facebook developer App (http://developers.facebook.com/apps) I get redirected to my regular facebook page. The community link (http://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/) does the same thing. I have tried clearing cookies, different browsers, nothing...

I just found/tried this link: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/?action=create, it also redirects me to my FB home page.

Yay, and the FB bug report tool (http://developers.facebook.com/bugs) is broken.

this is extremely frustrating, especially since there's no support on their site...

How do i get it to let me in?

Comment: Do you using Facebook as Page?

Comment: Than this isn't a case. Are you able to access documentation and developer tools (like [Graph API explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer))?

Comment: yup, i can see the Graph API explorer.

Comment: What was the last you have done on Facebook before you got thrown out? Maybe you should try to [reconfirm your developer account](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/386/).

Comment: i don't think i ever got thrown out. I haven't really done anything with this account since creating it, and I haven't received nor can I see any indication that I have been thrown out. When I click on that 'reconfirm' link it says my "mobile phone has been successfully verrified."

Comment: One more thing to check.  In the Graph API Explorer tool, do a GET command to `me/accounts` and see if you have any apps and pages under your control.

Comment: Did you have any previously setup for your account there? If so, were there other admins that could have removed you?  If not, then facebook removed you.

Comment: no, it's pretty much a new account with a profile photo. i can log into facebook just fine, so i don't think they removed me. i just can't access the developer app. it doesn't give me an error or anything, it just redirects me to my facebook homepage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't access it from a "page" account, you can only access it from a regular account. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9305641/450127).

Comment: In a better world they would flash a dialog that tells you this!