# Can't access Facebook Developers App!!?! Redirected to my page repeatedly

Tags: facebook, redirect

Each and every time I try to access the Facebook Developer's App it redirects me to my Entertainer Page. I have already verified the account after Facebook text messaged me an id code. I read in another post where the person said "only users accounts, not page accounts can access Facebook Developers App." However the poster did not specify anything further. Please can someone help me. I see I am not alone in having this issue. Thank you.

Comment: I believe it is an option under "Public Figure."

Comment: There is a page where you can select what type of page you want to create. There are 6 boxes on that page. I chose the public figure page and the option of Entertainer.

Comment: Sorry I can't find those options. Im not quite sure if we are talking about the same "Facebook Developer's App"? Is it https://developers.facebook.com/apps/?

Comment: Yes. How I just solved the problem was that I created an entirely separate account with Facebook. I went to facebook.com and filled out my information for a new account. I guess this is what is meant as a "User" Account. It is very silly how Facebook set this up. The Entertainer page I created must be considered a "page" account. One can not access the Facebook Developers App if you are in a "Page" account for some reason. Thank you anyway for your help. I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: I wrote your findings as an answer if somebody else would find this site. But you basically gave your answer in your question DUCY?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating and managing a Facebook app from a Business Account](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10805745/creating-and-managing-a-facebook-app-from-a-business-account)

Answer (score 8):

See comments above: The conclusion is that you can't access the Facebook Developer's App Page without a real facebook user account.