# How to create an app / a loop between developers.facebook.comm and profile page

Tags: facebook

this may seem elementary BUT
my e-commerce software provider tells me to go to

Create Apps (profile page) > Apps (developers.facebook.com) > and then I shuld be ont the Apps screen withe the Create App button

insted Im gettng a loop redirect from developers.facebook.com to profile page

What is happening? Is the Create App button somewhere else now?

Comment: Problem solved:
To create an application You have to use a "User account" not a "Page account" athough a Page Acunt can register to Facebook Developers, which is strange.

Answer found in:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305641/cant-access-facebook-developers-app-redirected-to-my-page-repeatedly

Answer (score 0):

Go here: https://developers.facebook.com/apps

1. If its your first app:

   Click `Register as Developer` button and continue.
2. Else, you'll see the `Create App` button at the top-right corner.